# How do I monitor elasticsearch's logs using Graylog?

Tags: elasticsearch, graylog2, graylog

I need to monitor elasticsearch's logs by using graylog. I setted up graylog but I am confused as to use which input type to monitor from log files of elasticserach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at these instructions: https://gist.github.com/joschi/e5d50048ddbcef038df9c4527b653ea9

- Download and extract Elasticsearch
- Download logstash-gelf and json-simple into the `./lib` directory of Elasticsearch:

  ```
  cd /path/to/elasticsearch/
  pushd ./lib
  wget http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/googlecode/json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1/json-simple-1.1.1.jar \
    http://central.maven.org/maven2/biz/paluch/logging/logstash-gelf/1.10.0/logstash-gelf-1.10.0.jar
  popd
  ```
- Add logstash-gelf appender to `config/logging.yml`:

  ```
  # you can override this using by setting a system property, for example -Des.logger.level=DEBUG
  es.logger.level: INFO
  rootLogger: ${es.logger.level}, console, file, gelf
  logger:
    # [...]
  appender:
    # [...]
    gelf:
      type: biz.paluch.logging.gelf.log4j.GelfLogAppender
      Host: "udp:127.0.0.1"
      Port: 12201
      Facility: elasticsearch
      ExtractStackTrace: true
      FilterStackTrace: true
      IncludeFullMdc: true
  ```
- Start Elasticsearch

### Remarks

If Graylog is not running or the configured GELF host is unreachable, you will see the following error messages at startup.
They can be ignored and are specific to the GELF appender (others might throw other exceptions or none at all):

```
[2016-06-22 16:31:46,451][INFO ][node                     ] [Jonothon Starsmore] version[2.3.2], pid[30390], build[b9e4a6a/2016-04-21T16:03:47Z]
[2016-06-22 16:31:46,462][INFO ][node                     ] [Jonothon Starsmore] initializing ...
log4j:ERROR null
java.io.IOException: Cannot send data to /127.0.0.1:12201
    at biz.paluch.logging.gelf.intern.sender.GelfUDPSender.sendDatagrams(GelfUDPSender.java:59)
    at biz.paluch.logging.gelf.intern.sender.GelfUDPSender.sendMessage(GelfUDPSender.java:49)
    at biz.paluch.logging.gelf.log4j.GelfLogAppender.append(GelfLogAppender.java:95)
    at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:856)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.log4j.Log4jESLogger.internalInfo(Log4jESLogger.java:120)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.support.AbstractESLogger.info(AbstractESLogger.java:81)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:151)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:140)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.build(NodeBuilder.java:143)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:178)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:270)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
Caused by: java.net.PortUnreachableException
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramDispatcher.write(DatagramDispatcher.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.write(DatagramChannelImpl.java:605)
    at biz.paluch.logging.gelf.intern.sender.GelfUDPSender.sendDatagrams(GelfUDPSender.java:56)
    ... 15 more
```